# Which is the difference between content page c# and content page xaml?

Tags: maui

When I want to create a new content page in a MAUI project, I have 2 options, ContentPage C#and ContentPage XAML.

Which is the difference between both of them?

There is some cases where is better to use one than the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One is a XAML file with a C# code behind.  The other is purely a C# class.

One is not inherently "better" than the other.  It is purely a matter of preference and coding style.